# Redirecting from https to http?

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect, ajax

Strange problem here.  I use FullCalendar to initiate an ajax request to an endpoint on my server. Endpoint is:

`https://my_website/events/?start=2019-03-31&end=2019-05-12&_=1555698739056`

Note that it is explicitly https. However, when I initiate a request (that is, when Fullcalendar initiates a request), I get a 301 and a redirect to a non-https endpoint:

`http://my_website/events?start=2019-03-31&end=2019-05-12&_=1555698739056`

which fails because the page is loaded over https.

[image]

The endpoint works fine - when i load it into the browser I get the expected json output (via https). There are other ajax requests happening on this page that work correctly, and I successfully do the exact same thing with Fullcalendar elsewhere on this site (to another endpoint). It's just this one scenario that is behaving unexpectedly.

Probably noteworthy is this sits in a docker container behind nginx reverse proxy / load balancer; site config is pretty simple:

```
upstream docker {
    server localhost:8701;
    server localhost:8702;
  }

server {
    server_name my_website;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://docker;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      # proxy_set_header                HTTP_Country-Code $geoip_country_code;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = my_website) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name my_website;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

And nginx log of the request is like this:

> 134.124.11.91 - - [19/Apr/2019:13:49:49 -0500] "GET /events/?start=2019-04-28&end=2019-06-09&_=1555699678658 HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "https://my_website" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"

Does anyone see something I'm missing that would be causing this strange 301 redirect to a non-https endpoint?

Comment: The nginx configuration you posted has no redirects. Check your application.

Answer (score 4):

The 301 redirect most probably comes from your backend server in the docker container. It is configured with the `http://...` url. Configure your application server in the container with the proper URL.

Comment: Why would it only be happening for a single endpoint?

Comment: There is no way to know that without knowing what is running on the backend and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 301 means permanent redirect and permanent means that browser's cache is always suspect. (That's why I always use HTTP 302 for weeks on any new version.) Clear all browser cache. Alternatively, google for a guide how to remove all cached 301 responses in your browser. They are quite sticky!

If you can, always use `curl -v http://x` to debug, it doesn't cache anything.

Comment: Even if this is a browser cache issue - which I don't think it is, because it is still happening across browsers even after I clear cache/cookies - I have a few hundred users. I can't expect all of them to clear their cache

Comment: @WillardSolutions Then try to debug directly `http://docker` and see if it gives you the redirect - maybe the nginx is somehow unable to intercept it... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache and change the redirection value to 
 if ($sceme = http) {
        return 301 https://my_website$request_uri